# How can I accept flexible dates in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

The GNU 'date' utility is awesome. I can feed it all sorts of dates and it can handle all of them, and convert them to whatever string format I want. Some examples are...

```
today
tomorrow
next thurs
next April
Aril 1
last year
1 month ago
2019-10-07
```

Is there an easy way to handle this flexibility with python3? I want to accept as many date formats as possible from the user, then convert them to `%Y-%m-%d` before printing to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have A look at dateparser library in python :

https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It will parse the above mentioned dates along with searching the dates in sentences, supporting different languages etc.

Comment: Nice. I was trying dateutils.parser earlier, but this looks like it fills in the gaps.